# Given a form submit, how to only submit if the server first responses back with a valid flag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form, with a text input and a submit button.

On submit, I want to hit the server first to see if the input is valid, then based on the response either show an error message or if valid, continue with the form submit.

Here is what I have:

```
$('#new_user').submit(function(e) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/users/stuff",
        data: $('#new_user').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data.valid) {
                return true
            } else {
                // Show error message
                return false;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is the form is always submitting, given the use case, what's the right way to implement? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to redirect to another page if the submit is successful, otherwise stay on the same page and show an error or validation message.  Is that accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('#new_user').submit(function(e) { 
    var $form = $(this);

    // we send an AJAX request to verify something
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/users/stuff",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data.valid) {
                // if the server said OK we trigger the form submission
                // note that this will no longer call the .submit handler
                // and cause infinite recursion
                $form[0].submit();
            } else {
                // Show error message
                alert('oops an error');
            }
        }
    });

    // we always cancel the submission of the form
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How does that not cause an infinite recursion?

Comment: Ooopooooops, sorry. My bad. Answer fixed. You should invoke the submit event on the underlying DOM element: `$form[0].submit();`. Now there's no infinite recursion because this event want invoke the callback.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  trying to understand reasoning(use case) for submit data via ajax, then resubmit same data through browser default again ..seems redundant

Comment: @charlietfl, completely agree with you. Me neither I don't see any use in doing such thing. The whole form data is sent to the server during this AJAX call, which is what happens when you submit the form normally. But since the OP asked about how this is possible to achieve I only answered that part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already submitting via AJAX why not just submit the data then if it's valid rather than transmit the data twice?

That said, the function that makes the Ajax call needs to be the one that returns false. Then the successvfunction should end with:

```
$('#new_user').submit()
```

The fact that AJAX is asynchronous is what's throwing you off.

Please forgive any typos, I'm doing this on my cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the same post to the server twice seems quite unnecessary.  I'm guessing you just want to stay on the same page if the form doesn't (or can't) be submitted successfully.  If I understand your intention correctly, just do a redirect from your success handler:

```
$('#new_user').submit(function(e) {  
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: "/users/stuff", 
        data: $('#new_user').serialize(), 
        success: function(data){ 
            location.href = "success.htm";
        },
        // if not valid, return an error status code from the server
        error: function () {
            // display error/validation messaging
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

EDIT: seems redundant submitting same data twice, not sure if this is what is intended. If server gets valid data on first attempt no point in resending

```
var isValid=false;
$('#new_user').submit(function(e) { 
    var $form = $(this);
     /* only do ajax when isValid is false*/
    if ( !isValid){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/users/stuff",
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.valid) {
                        isValid=true;
                        /* submit again, will bypass ajax since flag is true*/
                        $form.submit();

                    } else {
                        // Show error message
                        alert('oops an error');
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    /* will return false until ajax changes this flag*/
    return isValid;
});
```